# Scrollable div container disappears when elements removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this page built. I use a scrollable div container for the accounts. If I size my screen such that the scrollbar appears, then delete account elements (by clicking on them) until the scrollbar isn't needed, the entire container disappears.

Setting the position to static fixes this, but in the full page I use draggables, and when I set the leftWrap container to be position fixed, I can't drag the draggables out of the container.

Another strange thing going on is if you manually delete an account element in the chrome debugger after the container has disappeared, it will reappear. Adding css through chrome debugger does the same thing.

Does anybody have some insight on why this is happening, and how I can work around it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    body{
        overflow:hidden; /* hide scrollbar from main element */
    }

    .myDraggable {
        width: 15em; 
        height: 2.5em; 
        border:1px solid #999;
        text-align:center;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0em;
        margin-bottom:.5em;
        background-color:#99ff99;
        position: static;
    }

    #wrapLeft{
        float:left;
        padding-left:10%;
        height: 95vh;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        /*position: ; fixed /* why does this fix the problem? */
    }

    .account{
        display:block;
        font-size: 70%;
        padding-bottom: .15em;
        padding-top: .4em;
        padding-left: 1em;
        padding-right:1em;
    }

</style>
<body>
<div id="wrapLeft" style="z-index: 1;">
    <div class="myDraggable " id="15">
         <span class="account"> 0
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="myDraggable " id="16">
         <span class="account"> 1
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="myDraggable " id="17">
         <span class="account"> 2
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="myDraggable " id="18">
         <span class="account"> 3
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="myDraggable " id="19">
         <span class="account"> 4
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="myDraggable " id="20">
         <span class="account"> 5
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="myDraggable " id="21">
         <span class="account"> 6
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="myDraggable " id="22">
         <span class="account"> 7
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="myDraggable " id="23">
         <span class="account"> 8
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="myDraggable " id="24">
         <span class="account"> 9
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="myDraggable " id="25">
         <span class="account"> 10
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="myDraggable " id="26">
         <span class="account"> 11
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="myDraggable " id="27">
         <span class="account"> 12
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="myDraggable " id="28">
         <span class="account"> 13
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="myDraggable " id="29">
         <span class="account"> 14
        </span> 
    </div>
</div>

<script>

$('.myDraggable').click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
    console.log('click');

});
</script>
```

Comment: couldn't reproduce the issue in latest version of chrome with shared code. Removing jqueryui tag since it isn't used at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `float:left;` of the `#wrapLeft` solved this. I don't know why, though.

Comment: Good catch. I meant to type #wrapLeft

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Just get the rendered width of the container when the page loads and set a fixed width. It will work as long as you don't do anything in your script (later) that will change the width of the container or the elements inside.

```js
//wait until the page loads
window.onload = function(){
    var renderedWidth = document.getElementById('wrapLeft').offsetWidth;
    document.getElementById('wrapLeft').style.width = renderedWidth+'px';
  //collect the elements
  var myDraggableElements = document.getElementsByClassName('myDraggable');
  for(var i = 0; i != myDraggableElements.length; i++){
    //when each element is clicked; remove it
    myDraggableElements[i].onclick = function(){
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    };  
  };
};
```

```css
body{
    overflow:hidden; /* hide scrollbar from main element */
    }

    .myDraggable {
        width: 15em; 
        height: 2.5em; 
        border:1px solid #999;
        text-align:center;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0em;
        margin-bottom:.5em;
        background-color:#99ff99;
        position: static;
    }

    #wrapLeft{
        float:left;
        padding-left:10%;
        height: 95vh;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        /*position: ; fixed /* why does this fix the problem? */
    }

    .account{
        display:block;
        font-size: 70%;
        padding-bottom: .15em;
        padding-top: .4em;
        padding-left: 1em;
        padding-right:1em;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapLeft" style="z-index: 1;">
        <div class="myDraggable " id="15">
             <span class="account"> 0
            </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="myDraggable " id="16">
             <span class="account"> 1
            </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="myDraggable " id="17">
             <span class="account"> 2
            </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="myDraggable " id="18">
             <span class="account"> 3
            </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="myDraggable " id="19">
             <span class="account"> 4
            </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="myDraggable " id="20">
             <span class="account"> 5
            </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="myDraggable " id="21">
             <span class="account"> 6
            </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="myDraggable " id="22">
             <span class="account"> 7
            </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="myDraggable " id="23">
             <span class="account"> 8
            </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="myDraggable " id="24">
             <span class="account"> 9
            </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="myDraggable " id="25">
             <span class="account"> 10
            </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="myDraggable " id="26">
             <span class="account"> 11
            </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="myDraggable " id="27">
             <span class="account"> 12
            </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="myDraggable " id="28">
             <span class="account"> 13
            </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="myDraggable " id="29">
             <span class="account"> 14
            </span> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This answer actually still has the same problem. Remove elements from the scrollable div until the scrollbar isn't necessary. At this point the container disappears, on my chrome browser at least.

Comment: Are you sure? Look in the web inspector and see if the container still exits.

Comment: I have tested it in chrome. The element still exists but I can see you issue. I think it is a CSS problem.

Comment: Yes it still exists. Highlighting it shows its in the same position as always, it just isn't visible.

Comment: Is there any way to force the scrollbars to stay, or force a refresh like in chrome debugger? This is very puzzling to me. Perhaps I just made a mistake with my formatting? I'm still new to this

Comment: Looks like a possible bug. This didn't happen in Safari. I haven't tested it in other browsers. You may have to change your CSS in order to get around the bug.

Comment: Okay I will have to keep playing around with it. I've basically been guessing and checking at a solution.

Comment: You can try experimenting with a `div` container around your existing div and change the styles a bit.

Comment: Forgot a { brace around a CSS declaration. Part of the code didn't get copied over to the code snippet. I have an idea and I'll see if it works.

Comment: Strange. Setting max width to 250px works, 260+ doesnt. Basically, it seems that setting max width works if you set it such that there exists a horizontal scroll bar. Once its wide enough that there isn't a horizontal scrollbar, the same problem occurs.

Comment: Try it now. I think I figured it out!

Comment: That broke the appearance but the glitch was still occurring even without the css working. Now that you fixed the css problem the glitch is still there.

Comment: You need to have some kind of fixed width for the container or else it will flex when there aren't any elements inside.

Comment: I am running it with the container having max-width:260px; width: 260px; It works, SOMETIMES. I can't understand why. I am literally refreshing the page and clicking repeatedly and sometimes it works fine sometimes it disappears.